# How do I remove grid from this photo?

Tags: image-processing, postprocessing

I found this cat a month ago, and I'm not his owners' friend so the mosquito grid was the inevitable problem. I would like to post-process this photo to get rid of it, but I don't know exactly how this should be done and it would be interesting to see what can you do with this.

[image: meow]

**UPD: [link to higher resolution (4928x3264) and quality](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3BLwu7Vb2U-UW0teWFrcU1RREU/view?usp=sharing)** (fixed) (fixed again after Google Drive probably disabled direct links)

Comment: Maybe find the Fourier transform of the mosquito grid and subtract that from the frequency domain? It does seem to be quite a regular pattern.

Comment: My immediate thought is to use `Inpaint`, but then the problem becomes: how do I find an appropriate mask for `Inpaint`...

Comment: Somewhat ... `i1 = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/XroGQ.jpg"];
truncate[data_, f_] :=
  Module[{i, j},
   {i, j} = Floor[Dimensions[data]/Sqrt[f]];
   PadRight[Take[data, i, j], Dimensions[data], 0.]
   ];
id = Transpose[ImageData[i1, "Byte"], {3, 2, 1}];
t = FourierDCT /@ ((256 - #) & /@ id);
fdct = FourierDCT[truncate[#, 50], 3] & /@ t;
rfdct = Round[fdct];
ImageReflect[
 ColorCombine[Image[#, "Byte"] & /@ ((256 - #) & /@ rfdct)], 
 Left -> Top]`

Comment: The above by using `FourierDCT` docs example

Comment: That cat looks pissed.

Comment: Well, you have all their code; why don't you try it out yourself on the high-resolution image?

Comment: @Rahul, I don't have Mathematica software at this time ..(

Answer (score 59):

Here's a crude first attempt: First find the mosquito grid using `RidgeFilter`

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XroGQ.jpg"];
ridges = ImageAdjust[ColorConvert[RidgeFilter[img, 2], "Grayscale"]]
```

[image]

(Note that I'm using `ColorConvert` *after* `RidgeFilter`, so `RidgeFilter` can find ridges in all color channels. Since `RidgeFilter` is nonlinear, the order makes a difference.)

Next, binarize with a low threshold to get a mask:

```
mask = MorphologicalBinarize[ridges, {0.05, 0.5}]
```

[image]

And finally: use `Inpaint` magic (where `Diffusion` is a compromise between quality and time):

```
Inpaint[img, mask, Method -> "Diffusion"]
```

[image]

I've played around with a few alternatives for `mask`, but none of them produced significantly better results, so I'm sticking with the KISS version. Maybe someone else can use this as a basis for a better reconstruction.

---

**ADD** In response to @Rahul's comment, here's a different mask that removes more of the grid, and also darker parts of the grid.

I'm using two separate LoG filters for the X- and Y-parts of the grid

```
logX = ImageData@LaplacianGaussianFilter[img, {50, {1, 20}}];
logY = ImageData@LaplacianGaussianFilter[img, {50, {20, 1}}];
```

I then use the square (to get dark and bright details)...

```
{logX, logY} = Map[Total, #^2, {2}] & /@ {logX, logY};
```

and rescale the resulting grid with the "average grid brightness" in the area, to get a more or less homogeneous image of the grid:

```
{logX, logY} = 
  Rescale[#/(GaussianFilter[#, 10] + 10^-10)] & /@ {logX, logY};

grid = Image[Rescale@(logX + logY)];
```

[image]

which I then binarize:

```
mask = MorphologicalBinarize[Image@grid, {0.15, 0.5}]
```

[image]

and use for inpainting:

```
res = Inpaint[img, Dilation[mask, 1], Method -> "Diffusion"]
```

[image]

A zoom on the cat's face shows that the grid is mostly gone:

```
ImageTrim[res, {{1130, 630}}, 200]
```

[image]

but so are details of the whiskers, and every edge in the image has "grid-shaped artifacts" from the inpainting.

Comment: the cat looks well satisfied, +1.

Comment: That's a pretty fine result for a "first crude attempt"! +1, despite the first sub-result looking like Satan's cat ;-)

Comment: Well, if you zoom in, you can still see the grid, and the whiskers look more like "dashed" lines. Room for improvement, but I don't think you can get much further with `Inpaint`

Comment: I think the reason the grid is still left is because `RidgeFilter` looks for thin *bright* ridges, so in the regions where the grid is darker than the background, `RidgeFilter` is selecting parts *not* in the grid to be part of the mask. For illustration, take a look at `ImageMultiply[img, mask]` and zoom in on the white window frame behind the cat. Not sure what would be a better way of doing it though.

Comment: Thank you for answer. You might be willing to apply and tweak your solution to the same photo with higher resolution and quality. I've used Google Drive hosting instead of default Imgur -- see question UPD.

Comment: Fixed 403 error.

Answer (score 14):

I tried the FFT idea just to see what it looks like. Here is a very quick and dirty version

```
t = 80;
fft = Table[Fourier[img[[All, All, x]]], {x, 1, 3}];
fft[[All, t ;; 1356 - t, All]] = 0;
fft[[All, All, t ;; 2048 - t]] = 0;
red = Image[Re[InverseFourier[fft[[1, All, All]]]]];
green = Image[Re[InverseFourier[fft[[2, All, All]]]]];
blue = Image[Re[InverseFourier[fft[[3, All, All]]]]];
ImageAdjust[ColorCombine[{red, green, blue}, "RGB"], .7]
```

[image: Cat after low pass filtering]

Probably could be improved with a more sophisticated approach (wavelets?)

Comment: Thank you for answer. You might be willing to apply and tweak your solution to the same photo with higher resolution and quality. I've used Google Drive hosting instead of default Imgur -- see question UPD.

Comment: Well it was just a quick experiment as nikie's method produced very good results. I'll take another look, but I wasn't able to access the link for the higher resolution image (I get 403 forbidden).

Comment: Sorry about 403. Fixed now.

Comment: Played around with it quite a bit. Tried creating a mask to improve the result. Nothing really worked that well. It seems like there 'should' be a way to improve it, but none of my experiments accomplished much.